# Why this user hasn't got the association bonus on Super User

Tags: discussion, reputation, association-bonus

This user has more than 200 rep. On Stack overflow but why he hasn't got the +100 association bonus on Super User?

[image: User image]

Link to user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1629471/sam

Comment: This is a known bug. It's under review, which means SE developers are aware of the bug, and might fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because he joined the Super User community, before question votes became +10, so when he joined Super User, he only had 146 reputation.

Now he has 291 reputation, since up-vote reputation from questions became double than before, here is the post announcing question reputation doubled:

[Upvotes on questions will now be worth the same as upvotes on answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391250/upvotes-on-questions-will-now-be-worth-the-same-as-upvotes-on-answers)

Comment: @WasifHasan As of November 13th 2019, the upvotes for questions became worth 10 repuation, before it was only 5, whereas Sam joined Super User before this happened, that's why when he joined he had less than 200 reputation, so he couldn't get the association bonus.